# Applying css when user is at top of the page with animated navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the current code which hides/shows my navigation when the user scrolls up.

```
$.fn.moveIt = function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

 $(this).each(function(){
   instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
 });

window.onscroll = function(){
var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
instances.forEach(function(inst){
  inst.update(scrollTop);
});
}
}

var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
 this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
 };

// Initialization
$(function(){
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});

});
```

css

```
#s-nav {
position: fixed;
display: block;
z-index: 999;
width: 100%;
top: 0; left: 0;
}

#s-nav.nav-up { top: -80px; }
```

The functionality I want to include is applying specific css when the user reaches the top of the page (or very close).

Basically I want the navigation to be lower on the page when the user is at the top, then have the shown code to 'hide/show' it at the top of the page when the user scrolls through the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
  //check if it is at the top of the page
   if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
     //do your code here or add css using jquery
   }
});
```

Comment: Adding this outside the code removes the functionality of the other code

Comment: is it having conflicts? perhaps you can use [`no conflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: When I put that code above/below the function, the function does not perform

Comment: did it work? I just read your comment, and I'm about to test your code with my suggested answer. Actually that answer is most likely the idea of it but since you're using javascript you need a little tweaking for that. BTW I guess there are missing/misplaced curly braces in your javascript code.

Comment: The problem is that in the original code controls certain aspects of the div, so adding your code outside the function won't work, but it is the right answer to the question. Problem is my problem is more complex